# How to cached image the right way

Tags: flutter, dart

Im using [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package to display loading for my image but i think i used it wrong because after the loading progress disappear the image still not appear until a few seconds.

[image: ![enter image description here]

here is my CachedNetworkImage code

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: movie.poster.toString(),
            imageBuilder: (context, _) {
              return Image.network(
                movie.poster.toString(),
                height: 250,
                width: 164,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              );
            },
            placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
              height: 250,
              width: 164,
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
```

Comment: I think it's so normal for this to happen after the app is restarted. This package may be working correctly when the page is refreshed within the application.

Comment: Just remove the Image.network with some plain container. This is happening because the CachedNetworkImage is doing its job correctly but after it loads that image you are basically telling the CachedNetworkImage to call Image.network which will take its own time to download that image AGAIN.

Comment: Well the answer is really simple but it works :) :) :) thanks man you're awesome @UTKARSHSharma

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma can you post an answer so i can tag it as the answer of this post

Comment: @CCP Sure that will help me 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are returning an Image.network which will again load the image, so you are getting this delayed image.

Replace Your Cached network image with this .

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: movie.poster.toString(),
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvioder) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvioder, fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
      );
    },
    placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
      height: 250,
      width: 164,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  ),
```

I Hope this helps.